# Why is the winding number homotopy invariant?

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology

It many sources it's stated that the winding number is invariant under homotopy, but I've yet to actually see why.

Suppose you have the [formal definition](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Winding_number#Formal_definition) of the winding number. So for a continuous loop $\gamma\colon[\alpha,\beta]\to\mathbb{C}\setminus\{a\}$ which doesn't pass through a point $a$, one has the function $\theta(t)=\text{arg}(\gamma(t)-a)\in\mathbb{R}/2\pi\mathbb{Z}$. By the lifting lemma, there exists a continuous $\tilde{\theta}\colon[\alpha,\beta]\to\mathbb{R}$, such that $[\tilde{\theta}(t)]=\theta(t)$, and the winding number of $\gamma$ around $a$ is then defined as $$n(\gamma,a)=\frac{\tilde{\theta}(\beta)-\tilde{\theta}(\alpha)}{2\pi}.$$

Is there a straightforward proof that the winding number is invariant under homotopy with this definition for continuous loops which do not pass through $a$? Thanks.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If you have a homotopy $H : [\alpha, \beta] \times [0; 1] \to \mathbb{C}\setminus \{a \}$, the function $\theta :  [\alpha, \beta] \times [0; 1] \to \mathbb{R}/2 \pi \mathbb{Z}$ defined by $\theta(x,t) = \arg(H(x,t)-a)$ is continuous in both variables, and can be lifted into a function $\tilde{\theta}$.

Then you can define the continuous function $n(t) = \frac {\tilde \theta (\beta,t) - \tilde \theta (\alpha,t)}{2 \pi} \in \mathbb{Z}$.
Since $\mathbb{Z}$ is discrete, it has to be a constant map, so the winding numbers of $\gamma = H(.,0)$ and $H(.,1)$ are the same.