# How to show that a chain is homologous to zero

Tags: general-topology, homotopy-theory, curves

Hey my first question here, so I got an exercise but need some help.
The questions is:

I have a domain $U\subset\mathbb{C}$, and curves $\gamma_j : [0, 1] \to U$, $j \in \{0, 1\}$ which are continuously differentiable.

They have the same start and end point, so $\gamma_0(0) = \gamma_1(0) = z_0$ and $\gamma_0(1) = \gamma_1(1) = z_1$. There is also a Homotopy between these points, $H : [0, 1] \times [0, 1] \to U$ with $H(0, \cdot) = \gamma_0$, $H(1, \cdot) = \gamma_1$, $H(\cdot, 0) = z_0$ and $H(\cdot, 1) = z_1$.

Show $\Gamma = \gamma_0 - \gamma_1$ is homologous to zero.

Here is the definition of homologous to zero:

If $\Gamma$  is in  $U$ and if $Int(\Gamma) \subset U$, then $\Gamma$ is called homologous to zero.
With $Int(\Gamma) = \{z\in\mathbb{C}\setminus[\Gamma]\mid ind_\Gamma(z) \neq 0\}$. $Int(\Gamma)$ is called *Interior* and $ind_\Gamma(z)$ is called *winding number*.

I probably have to show that $ind_{\gamma_0}(z) = ind_{\gamma_1}(z) \ \forall z \notin U$. 
Which probably implies $Int(\gamma_0 - \gamma_1) = Int(\Gamma) \subset U$ and therefore $\Gamma$ is homologous to zero.

Any ideas how to do this? Thanks in advance!

EDIT:

I think I got something but maybe there are some arguments missing:

Proof:

Let $z\in\mathbb{C} \setminus U$. Since $H$ is continuously differentiable, the mapping $$j \mapsto ind_{\gamma_j}(z) = \frac{1}{2\pi i}\int_{\gamma_j} \frac{1}{\xi - z}d\xi = \frac{1}{2\pi i}\int_0^1 \frac{1}{H(j, t) - z}\frac{\partial^2 H(j,t)}{\partial j \partial t} dt$$ is continuously from $[0, 1]$ to $\mathbb{R}$. Also, the values from this map are in $\mathbb{Z}$. Therefore, the mapping is constant.

This implies $ind_{\gamma_0}(z) = ind_{\gamma_1}(z) \ \forall z \notin U$.

Which implies $Int(\gamma_0 - \gamma_1) = Int(\Gamma) \subset U$ and therefore $\Gamma$ is homologous to zero. $\Box$

Comment: I think the phrase you're looking for is "homologous to zero."

Comment: Your question does not make much sense. How is the subtraction $\gamma_0 - \gamma_1$ defined? How is $Int(\Gamma)$ defined? And "Is $\Gamma$ in $U$ and is $Int(\Gamma) \subset U$, so $\Gamma$ is called null-homolog" is not even a grammatical sentence, let alone a reasonable definition of what is called "homologous to zero" in English.

Comment: @D.Brogan thank! I'll have a look maybe I'll find something regarding this :)

Comment: @LeeMosher sorry, english isn't my first language so I'm sorry for grammatical errors. Regarding your questions, we never explicitly defined $\gamma_0 - \gamma_1$. $Int(\Gamma)$ is an open subset, I have defined it in my post. Well, besides the grammatical error this is unfortunately the defintion my professor gave us.

*I edited the post now, hopefully it's grammatically now a bit more correct :)

Comment: Although $\gamma_0 - \gamma_1$ is not explicitly defined, it is fairly obvious that it is the closed path based at $z_0$ composed by $\gamma_0$ (path from $z_0$ to $z_1$) and the inverse of $\gamma_1$ (path from $z_1$ to $z_0$).

Comment: @PaulFrost That's arguable. It seems more likely that $\gamma_0 - \gamma_1$ is a formal linear combination of $\gamma_0$ and $\gamma_1$ (with integer coefficients). This only becomes equal to the composed path if the group of chains is quotiented by a subgroup containing all chains of the form $\gamma_2 - \gamma_0 + \gamma_1$, where $\gamma_2$ is the path composed from $\gamma_0$ and $\gamma_1$. Ahlfors, for example (p.137f. of the third edition of *Complex Analysis*) only hints at this and doesn't bother to formalise it. Indeed, it doesn't make much difference to the proof. Excuse my quibble!

Comment: I assume the statement "$H(\cdot, 0) = z_0$ and $H(\cdot, 1) = z_1$" (which doesn't quite make sense, as it stands) means $H(t, 0) = z_0$ and $H(t, 1) = z_1$ for all $t \in [0, 1]$.

Comment: We used to define the summation of paths like this: $\Gamma = \sum{a_j \ \gamma_j}$ with $a_j$ being a coefficient. In this case $a_0 = 1$ and $a_1 = -1$.

Comment: @CalumGilhooley yeah I think my professor just meant it in that way.

Comment: @CalumGilhooley You are certainly right that the best interpretation of $\gamma_0 - \gamma_1$ is that of a chain (in the sense of singular homology) as done by Ahlfors. However, the winding number $ind_\Gamma(z)$ of $z$ with respect to $\Gamma = \gamma_0 - \gamma_1$ is only defined for closed curves which suggests that $\Gamma$ should not be regarded as a formal sum.

Comment: @PaulFrost As I understand it, the winding number is defined for all curves, but is in general non-integral. I must admit to persistently misreading the question as if the curves were closed, though! I nearly sketched a proof based on this mistaken assumption. More seriously, the few references I've just checked (apart from Beardon, *Complex Analysis* (1979) and Garling, *A Course of Mathematical Analysis* (3 vols. 2013-4)) do seem to define the winding number only for closed curves.

Comment: I added a proof, if you want, you can check if this is correct or if there are some arguments missing.

Comment: @CalumGilhooley You can of course define a "winding number" for non-closed curves (in general taking a non-integral value), but in my opinion it does make much sense. In his proof the OP argues with the winding number of general curves, but since the values are in general non-integral, his proof breaks down.

Comment: @Xvid Your proof doesn't work. See my above comment. I recommend to have a look at https://math.stackexchange.com/q/112679.

Comment: @PaulFrost we used something similar in a proof for a previous Proposition. My teacher also told me we should do basically the same thing. I'll check this tomorrow again, will update the post eventually.

Comment: (1) How were winding numbers defined? The definition in terms of integrals requires curves to be closed. (The "lifting" definition does not.) So, were the curves $\gamma_0,\gamma_1$ always meant to be closed? (2) The integral definition requires curves to be rectifiable. (Again, "lifting" doesn't.) Continuous differentiability is certainly enough. But exactly what conditions are imposed on the homotopy, especially on the boundary of its domain? You mentioned no conditions on $H$ before. Continuity was implicit, of course. That alone suffices to prove much, so are calculus complications needed?

Answer (score 1):

The discussion in the comments shows that some concepts need to be clarified. Here is a pragmatic approach.

You start with curves $\gamma_j : [0, 1] \to U$, $j \in \{0, 1\}$, which are continuously differentiable. Let us assume that the homotopy $H : I \times I \to U$ from $\gamma_0$ to $ \gamma_1$ is a continuous map which is partially differentiable with respect to the second coordinate (i.e. $\dfrac{\partial H}{\partial s}(t,s)$ exists for all $(t,s) \in I \times I$) and such that $\dfrac{\partial H}{\partial s} : I \times I \to \mathbb C$ is continuous. This implies that all intermediate curves $H_t = H(t,-)$, $t \in I$, are continuously differentiable. This requirement is a little bit weaker than assuming that $H$ is continuously differentiable (this concept would need further clarification).

Let us moreover agree that the winding number $ind_\gamma(z)$ is defined for closed piecewise continuously differentiable curves $\gamma$ and all $z \notin \gamma(I)$. The winding number is always an integer given by
$$ind_\gamma(z) = \frac{1}{2\pi i} \int_\gamma \frac{1}{\zeta-z}d\zeta = \frac{1}{2\pi i} \int_0^1 \frac{\gamma'(s)}{\gamma(s)-z}ds .$$

Finally we regard $\Gamma = \gamma_0 - \gamma_1$ as a closed curve based at $z_0$. It is composed by $\gamma_0$ (path from $z_0$ to $z_1$) followed by the inverse of $\gamma_1$ (path from $z_1$ to $z_0$). Explicitly, $\Gamma(s) =
\begin{cases}
\gamma_0(2s) & s \le 1/2 \\
\gamma_1(2-2s) & s \ge 1/2
\end{cases} \quad$ .

Let us define a homotopy $G : I \times I \to U, G(t,s) = 
\begin{cases}
H(t,s) & s \le 1/2 \\
\gamma_1(2-2s) & s    \ge 1/2
\end{cases} \quad$ .
This is a homotopy from $G_0 = \Gamma$ to $G_1 = \gamma_1 - \gamma_1$ such that all $G_t$ are piecewise continuously differentiable curves.

By definition $G(I\times I) \subset U$. It therefore suffices to show that for all $z \in \mathbb C \setminus G(I\times I)$ we have $ind_\Gamma(z) = 0$ because this implies that $Int(\Gamma) \subset G(I\times I) \subset U$.

For $z \in \mathbb C \setminus G(I\times I)$ we obviously have $ind_{G_1}(z) = \frac{1}{2\pi i} \int_{\gamma_1} \frac{1}{\zeta-z}d\zeta - \frac{1}{2\pi i} \int_{\gamma_1} \frac{1}{\zeta-z}d\zeta = 0$. We want to prove that $ind_\Gamma(z) = ind_{G_0}(z) = 0$. To do this, it has to be shown that the function
$$\phi : I \to \mathbb Z, \phi(t) =  \frac{1}{2\pi i} \int_0^1 \frac{G_t'(s)}{G_t(s)-z}ds$$
is continuous and therefore constant. I shall not give a proof but leave it as an excercise to you.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to everyone, I'll provide the solution from my teacher which seems, at least for me, a bit more easier to understand.

We have to show that $Int(\Gamma) = Int(\gamma_0 - \gamma_1) \subset U$, or in other words $ind_{\Gamma}(z) = ind_{\gamma_0 - \gamma_1}(z) = 0 \ \forall z \notin U$.

Let us define the mapping

$$\eta_s(z) : [0, 1] \to \mathbb{R}, s \mapsto ind_{\gamma_0 - \gamma_s}(z) \ \forall z \notin U$$

$$\rightarrow ind_{\gamma_0 - \gamma_s}(z) = \frac{1}{2 \pi i} \int_{\gamma_0 - \gamma_s} \frac{d\zeta}{\zeta - z}= \frac{1}{2 \pi i} \int_{\gamma_0} \frac{d\zeta}{\zeta - z} - \frac{1}{2 \pi i} \int_{\gamma_s} \frac{d\zeta}{\zeta - z}$$

The first term is obviously constant, as he doesn't vary.
The second term can we rewrite as:

$$- \frac{1}{2 \pi i} \int_{\gamma_s} \frac{d\zeta}{\zeta - z} = - \frac{1}{2 \pi i} \int_0^1 \frac{\gamma_s^\prime(t)}{\gamma_s(t) - z} dt.$$

We know, from some previous Proposition from our lecture, that this is continuous and $\in \mathbb{Z}$, therefore this one is constant too.

$\Rightarrow \eta_s(z) = const.$

We only have to calculate now what the value of $\eta_s(z)$ for every $s\in [0,1]$ is (as it's constant).

Let $s = 0 \rightarrow \eta_0(z) = ind_{\gamma_0 - \gamma_0}(z) = 0$.

Therefore, $\eta_1(z) = ind_{\gamma_0 - \gamma_1}(z) = ind_{\Gamma}(z) = 0 \ \forall z \notin U$. $\Rightarrow Int(\Gamma) \subset U$ and therefore $\Gamma$ is homologous to zero.

With this, one can also easily come to the homotpy version of Cauchy's integral theorem.

*It's probably not a perfect proof but this kinda works out for me, sorry for grammar errors*

Comment: The proof is not correct. You consider the function $I(s) = -\frac{1}{2 \pi i} \int_{\gamma_s} \frac{d\zeta}{\zeta - z} = - \frac{1}{2 \pi i} \int_0^1 \frac{\gamma_s^\prime(t)}{\gamma_s(t) - z} dt$ and claim that it is continuous (which is certainly true) and an *integer* which is not true. An integral of the form $\frac{1}{2 \pi i} \int_{\gamma} \frac{d\zeta}{\zeta - z}$ only takes integer values for closed curves.

Comment: However, you can easily repair it. Although $I(s) = -\frac{1}{2 \pi i} \int_{\gamma_s} \frac{d\zeta}{\zeta - z}$ doesn't take integer values, it is *continuous* and therefore also $\eta_s$ is continuous. But $\eta_s$ takes integer values and thus is constant.

Comment: @PaulFrost thanks! Maybe I missed this argument but yeah make sense.