# Why can't there be a retraction $r:D\to S^1$ from a disk to its boundary?

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology, retraction

I am watching [these lectures on algebraic topology on youtube](https://youtu.be/CSC5Q6ULWrg) by NJ Wildberger. At around [9:00](https://youtu.be/CSC5Q6ULWrg?t=541) they give an informal proof that there is no retraction $r:D\to S^1$ from the disk to its boundary.

I understand a retraction to be here a continuous mapping $r:D\to S^1$ such that $r(p)=p$ for all $p\in S^1$. The idea of the given proof, as far as a I understand it, is as follows:

1. Suppose there is such a retraction $r:D\to S^1$.
2. Consider continuous deformations of $r$ of the form $$p_t \equiv r\circ [\text{contraction by }(1-t)].$$
   These maps will then be such that $p_0=r$, whereas $p_1:\{(0,0)\}\to r(0,0)\in S^1$ maps the center of the disk into some point on the circle.
3. Consider a loop $\gamma$ on $S^1$. Consider the corresponding loops $p_t(\gamma):s\mapsto p_t(\gamma(s))$. Then $p_0(\gamma)=\gamma$ has winding number $1$, whereas $p_1(\gamma):s\mapsto r(0,0)$ is just a fixed point. Continuous deformations cannot change the winding number, thus there cannot be any such retraction.

I think I'm missing something with regards to this invariance of the winding number with respect to continuous deformations.
I'm picturing the situation as considering how loops around $(0,0)$ with different radii get mapped by $r$.

Is there a more formal way to see why such deformations of $r$ cannot change the winding number? I could imagine a situation where $p_t(\gamma)$ is a loop on $S^1$, whereas $p_{t+\epsilon}$ is not a loop but rather a "slightly open" loop. I can imagine such opening to happen continuously. Why could such a behaviour not correspond to a continuous mapping $t\mapsto p_t(\gamma)$?

Comment: Not helpful to this question, but it may interest you that this theorem is immediately usable to prove Brouwer's fixed-point theorem:  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brouwer_fixed-point_theorem#A_proof_using_homology

Comment: @Alan indeed, that's actually what the speaker shows in the video immediately after this! It is quite a beautiful proof I have to say

Comment: You can see this no retraction result more easily by knowing that the fundamental group of $D$ is the trivial group whilst the fundamental group of  the circle is $\mathbb{Z} $. If there were a retraction there would be a surjective homomorphism between these two groups.

Comment: Which definition  of winding number do you use?

Comment: @PaulFrost as the number of times a closed curve loops around the center (I'm aware it's kind of an informal definition at this level). Also equal to the number of intersections with the loop of a line going from the center towards any direction (counting the different directions with different signs)

Comment: @glS are you asking why winding number is homotopy invariant? https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/112679/why-is-the-winding-number-homotopy-invariant

Comment: @freakish I suppose yes, the question probably boils down to that. The question you link seems to be a bit different though. For one thing, it's about winding number in the context of complex analysis. Is this equivalent to the purely geometrically minded case discussed here?